# Specify GPU in Info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit

Is it possible to specify the minimum GPU requirement in plist?  I would like to require (iOS GPU family 3) Apple A9 devices.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlfeatureset

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `arkit` key in plist to support only the iOS device family with an A9 or later processor.

Comment: Not sure if binary is going to be rejected by Apple for arkit key when the app doesn't has any AR features